# Como eu poderia implementar esse código para que, se eu digitar "a" como 0 o programa pare imediatamente e apareça a mensagem "FIM"?

Tags: python

```
def conta(x,y,z):
     return (a**b)+c


a = int(input('Infome a: '))
if a == 0:
    print('FIM')
b = int(input('Infome b: '))
c = int(input('Infome c: '))

result = conta(a,b,c)
print(result)
```

Comment: Ignorem o "N" no final da pergunta...

Comment: _pare_ no sentido de pausar, ou encerrar o programa? Para encerrar o programa imediatamente você pode invocar a função `exit(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa forma você consegue:

```
def conta(x,y,z):
     return (a**b)+c

a = int(input('Infome a: '))
if a != 0:
    b = int(input('Infome b: '))
    c = int(input('Infome c: '))
    result = conta(a,b,c)
    print(result)
else:
    print('FIM')
```

'Puxei' o `result = conta(a,b,c)` e o `print(result)` pra dentro do if, dai eles só serão executados caso a seja diferente de zero.

Alteração do código conforme o jsbueno sugeriu:

```
import sys

def conta(x,y,z):
     return (a**b)+c

a = int(input('Infome a: '))
if a != 0:
    b = int(input('Infome b: '))
    c = int(input('Infome c: '))
    result = conta(a,b,c)
    print(result)
else:
    print('FIM')
    sys.exit(0)
```

Caso esteja utilizando o Anaconda possivelmente vai apresentar uma mensagem ao final da execução.

Comment: Essa forma é mais elegante - mas a pegutna realemtne requer uma informação que está faltando aí pra ser completa: para encerrar um programa Python em um ponto arbitrário deve se chamar `sys.exit(0)`  (precedido por um  `import sys`)  - Consegue adicionar isso na sua resposta? Aí ela fica completinha para os próximos leitores.

Answer (score 3):

Adicione um else. Seu código ficará assim:

```
def conta(x,y,z): 
    return (a**b)+c

a = int(input('Infome a: ')) 
if a == 0: 
    print('FIM')
else:
    b = int(input('Infome b: ')) 
    c = int(input('Infome c: '))
    
    result = conta(a,b,c) 
    print(result)
```